Dynamic routing with Azure VPN Gateway and with inspection by NVA
I'm searching for possibility to implement a topology like this:
Spoke VNETs <====> NVA, for instance FortiGate <=====> VPN Gateway <=====> on-premises

To implement this with static routing is pretty straightforward, but has irritating limitations:

If I place the NVA and the VPN Gateway in the same HUB-VNET, while enabling the Enable Spoke-VNET to use HUB-VNET's remote gateway or route server option - then narrow on-premises prefixes learned from VPN Gateway will override more generic prefixes in Spoke-VNET UDRs, which steer traffic towards on-premises to the NVA for inspection. I'll need to override each one of them in the UDRs, which is not practical.

If I place them in the same HUB-VNET without enabling this option, or if I place the VPN Gateway in a VNET not peered directly with Spokes - then the VPN Gateway won't know IP ranges of Spoke VNETs. It still will deliver traffic for them to the NVA by means of a UDR applied to its GatewaySubnet - but if the VPN Gateway will learn some prefix overlapping with Spoke VNET's prefix from one of its BGP-over-IPsec peers - it will send the traffic there instead of delivering it to the NVA, and communication will fail.


Example:

UDR of GatewaySubnet says "deliver traffic to 10.0.0.0.0/0 via NVA".
The Spoke VNET's range is 10.11.12.0/24.
If the VPN Gateway doesn't learn it automatically from the SDN, while learning a prefix 10.11.0.0/16 from some its BGP peer - then traffic to 10.11.12.0/24 will be sent to this peer instead of the Spoke.


I'm looking for solution that would:

Allow Spoke VNETs to deliver traffic to the NVA - without me having to override by UDRs each narrow prefix injected to them by the VPN Gateway.

Allow the VPN Gateway to learn automatically prefixes of Spoke VNETs - while still delivering traffic to them via the NVA.


Is such this possible? With Azure Route Server or without?
Thanks!
Mucius.

Let's say VPN Gateway will learn Spoke VNETs ranges from NVA - by means of BGP peerings: VPN Gateway <====> Route Server <=====> NVA.
But then the question is: how the NVA can discover the VNETs' ranges?
Is it possible somehow to add a static route to the VPN Gateway's own routing table, saying something like deliver packets for 10.11.0.0/16 to the SDN (lowest IP of GatewaySubnet)?
I mean not the UDR applying to packets already delivered by the Gateway to SDN - but the routing table inside the Gateway's instances.

Found a solution, but it comes with limitations:

only one firewall instance can serve the Spokes;
another component, Azure Route Server, is required.

More details at https://github.com/cat-mucius/kb/wiki/Dynamic-routing-with-Azure-VPN-Gateway-and-with-traffic-inspection-by-custom-firewall.

Update: judging by the "Direct routing to NVA instances for dual-role connectivity and firewall NVAs" section in Virtual WAN documentation, Microsoft themselves didn't find a good active-active solution for this problem. :-)

Azure's software-defined networking platform doesn't guarantee
flow-level symmetry, meaning the inbound flow to Azure and outbound
flow from Azure can land on different instances of the NVA. This
results in asymmetric routing which is dropped by stateful firewall
inspection. Therefore, it isn't recommended to use active-active
connectivity patterns where an NVA is behaving as a dual-role NVA
unless the NVA can support asymmetric forwarding or support session
sharing/synchronization.

